# Gerrit disable pushing of empty patch-sets

Tags: git, gerrit

In older versions of Gerrit when trying to do a push of a commit with a different SHA, but no changes - so no changes in the commit message, no changes in the commit content, and no changes in its ancestors you would get an error like this:

```
remote: (W) No changes between prior commit a5ff9c3 and new commit 014229a
To ssh://developer@gerritserver:29418/projectX
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (no changes made)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://developer@gerritserver:29418/projectX'
```

So Gerrit wouldn't allow you to push an empty patch-set.
This was the behavior on some 2.X Gerrit versions.

Now when using 3.1.4 there is only the warning:

```
remote: warning: no changes between prior commit c94b74a and new commit 19e07aa
remote: 
remote: SUCCESS
```

And everything passes well after that. This means that if you do a cherry-pick and push to Gerrit you create an empty patch-set, which isn't what I would consider good behavior.

Is there a way to force the same behavior as the previous Gerrit versions? I tried with the `Reject empty commit upon submit` configuration in the project settings and at first, I thought it's working, but that doesn't seem to be the correct option to change.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, this option has an effect only when a change is merged, but maybe it also has an effect when the commit is pushed (it's a bug or a feature?).

See the "submit.rejectEmptyCommit" option in the "Submit section" on the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-project-config.html#submit-section).

Comment: I tried reading the documentation regarding the submit policy, but couldn't get my head around it. By default, the submit action should be "Merge if necessary" if I remember correctly and it's the same on older and newer Gerrit version. So that part doesn't seem related to this.
On the other hand, I expected the rejectEmptyCommit to have an impact, but it seems it's only applicable to commits that are actually empty and try to be merged, so again it has nothing to do with patch sets...